# Legend label showing the same interval more than once

Tags: r, maps, legend

I'm making a shaded map in R. The legend create separate categories for zero and missing but it labels both of them "[0,0)"

Any idea how to fix this?

```
library(gpclib)
library(maptools)     # loads sp library too
library(RColorBrewer) # creates nice color schemes
library(classInt)     # finds class intervals for continuous variables


CAcounty.shp <- readShapePoly(file.choose(),proj4string=CRS("+proj=longlat"))

 plotvar <- CAcounty.shp@data$mediresp
 nclr <- 8
 plotclr <- brewer.pal(nclr,"BuPu")
 class <- classIntervals(plotvar, nclr, style="quantile")
 colcode <- findColours(class, plotclr)

 plot(CAcounty.shp, xlim=c(-122.5, -117), ylim=c(32,42))
 plot(CAcounty.shp, col=colcode, add=T) 

XXXXX <- read.csv("XXXXXXXX.csv")
plotvar <- XXXXX$XXXXXX 

title(main=“XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
sub=“Internal Data")
legend(-119, 42, legend=names(attr(colcode, "table")),
    fill=attr(colcode, "palette"), cex=0.6, bty="n")
 plotclr <- brewer.pal(nclr,"RdYlGn")
 colcode <- findColours(class, plotclr)
points(KPhosp$lon, KPhosp$lat, pch=16, col=colcode, cex=1)
```

Comment: Isn't the actual problem that `names(attr(colcode,'table'))` is returning identical text strings for both cases?

Comment: Most of that code is irrelevant tot he problem. You dont need the map stuff to show the problem, just generate plotvar and plotclr and give us something we can cut n paste.

Comment: I can't get legend to give me *any* category for missing data. _shrug_

Answer (score 1):

This shows something like that for me, but your supposition is wrong:

```
plotvar=c(rep(NA,20),rep(0,20),1:10)
nclr <- 8
plotclr <- brewer.pal(nclr,"BuPu")
class <- classIntervals(plotvar, nclr, style="quantile")
colcode <- findColours(class, plotclr)

plot(1:10)

legend(5,5, legend=names(attr(colcode, "table")),
    fill=attr(colcode, "palette"), cex=0.6, bty="n")
```

that produces a legend with lots of [0,0) values, which are all indeed zeroes (not missing values - check by removing the NAs from the vector, nothing changes).

Its because I've got 8 quantile breaks but so many zeroes they fill more than one of the quantiles.

If that's your problem, then you need to think about another way of mapping values to colours, and its nothing to do with missing values!

Here's some similar code that shows how to add an extra item to the legend to indicate what happens to items with NA colours:

```
set.seed(310366)
x=1:30
y=30*runif(30)
plotvar=sample(5+10*c(rep(NA,20),runif(10)))
nclr <- 8
plotclr <- brewer.pal(nclr,"Spectral")
class <- classIntervals(plotvar, nclr, style="quantile")
colcode <- findColours(class, plotclr)

plot(x,y,col="black",pch=21,bg=colcode)

legend(5,10, legend=c("Missing",names(attr(colcode, "table"))),
    fill=c("white",attr(colcode, "palette")), cex=0.6, bty="n")
```

I think you have to do this manually. Its no big problem.

Comment: Thanks, reducing the number of levels improved the graph but the county that has a blank in the .dbf portion of the shapefile for the plot variable is still being categozied as zero.

Comment: The colcode for a region that has NA is also NA, and so that region won't get filled. When I try it, the regions look like white regions. Its not being "categorized as zero", its just not being filled, which seems reasonable for missing data. If you can adjust your question so we can cut n paste and get the same problem as you are having then we can move on. At the moment its just "works for me" (which is why you've been scored down!).

Comment: Just to be clear, I said the LEGEND was categorizing missing as zero. The map prints the county with missing data in white which is perfect. The legend, however, reads:              WHITE-- [0,0); LIGHT BLUE -- [0,0) BLUE -- [0, 0.1), etc. I would expect WHITE -- N/A or just blank.

Comment: Its not. You've still got two categories for zero, and your palette has that first category as white, which happens to be the background colour that your NA-valued polygons are showing as. I bet if you added 5 to all your values you'd get two intervals with [5,5). I think you need to add a couple of things to the legend to show the NA values...